# why block.number gives underflow error on line no 101 while i am excluding the previous from the lastest so it shouldn't behave like this

Tags: solidity, blockchain, cpp-ethereum

**below is a function snippet**
**the line responsible for error is below**

```
   uint256 currentBlocks = block.number;
   p.endedAt = currentBlocks;
   uint256 blocks = (p.endedAt -= p.startedAt);
   console.log("the amount of block's played",blocks);
   require(p.endedAt > p.startedAt,"no block's played");
   p.durationPlayed += blocks;

 function joinPot(uint256 _potId)
        external
        payable
        potFreezed(_potId)
        userBlackListed
        
    {
        Pot storage pot = createdPots[_potId];
        require( _potId != 0 && _potId <= potId ,"invalid Pot Id"); //pot instance
        require(
            pot.potBalance > 0.01 ether,
            "pot balance isn't valid to play further"
        );
        require(msg.value == partcipationFee,"pay fee to join the pot");
        //getting length of current pot player
        uint256 currentSize = pot.participants.length;
        participant storage p = pot.participants[currentSize - 1];
        uint256 currentBlocks = block.number;
        p.endedAt = currentBlocks;
        uint256 blocks = (p.endedAt -= p.startedAt);
        console.log("the amount of block's played",blocks);
        require(p.endedAt > p.startedAt,"no block's played");
        p.durationPlayed += blocks;
        console.log(p.durationPlayed);
        uint256 durationReference = p.durationPlayed;
        //now count reward total
        bool rewardMonitor;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i <= durationReference; i++) {
            uint256 percentPerSecond = (pot.potBalance *
                rewardPerSecondPercent) / 10000;
            p.reward += percentPerSecond;
            //PER SECOND REWARD ADDED TO THE LAST USER REWARD
            pot.potBalance -= percentPerSecond;
            if (p.reward > pot.potBalance) {
                rewardMonitor = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rewardMonitor) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value);
            pot.claimingActive = true;
           console.log("claiming is activated");
            //reward claiming will be activated
        } else if (!rewardMonitor) {
            uint256 ownerCut = ((msg.value * 55) / 100);
            uint256 teamCut = ((msg.value * 5) / 100);
            uint256 previousPlayers = ((msg.value * 20) / 100);
            uint256 potBalanceSubmit = ((msg.value * 20) / 100);
            payable(pot.creator).transfer(ownerCut);
            payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2).transfer(
                teamCut
            );
            if (currentSize == 1) {
                payable(pot.participants[0].userAddress).transfer(
                    previousPlayers
                );
            } else if (currentSize > 1) {
                uint256 divideAmong = previousPlayers / currentSize;
                for (uint256 i = 0; i < currentSize; i++) {
                    payable(pot.participants[i].userAddress).transfer(
                        divideAmong
                    );
                }
            }
            pot.potBalance += potBalanceSubmit;
            //now reward distribution
            // uint256 accessReward = pot.participants[currentSize -5].reward;

            //from there
            uint256 startIndex;
            uint256 lastIndex;

            if (currentSize > 5) {
                startIndex = currentSize - 5;
                lastIndex = currentSize;
                console.log("reward when greater than 5");
                uint256 playerReward = pot.participants[startIndex].reward;
                // uint256 startingFrom = currentSize-5;
                console.log(
                    "strting in there from",
                    pot.participants[startIndex].userAddress
                );
                for (uint256 i = startIndex; i < lastIndex; i++) {
                    // console.log("the index is", currentSize - 5);
                    // uint256 toSend = playerReward*distribution[i]/100;
                    uint256 toSend = (playerReward *
                        distribution[i - startIndex]) / 100; // Changed this line

                    // console.log("sending to", pot.participants[i].userAddress);
                    payable(pot.participants[i].userAddress).transfer(toSend);
                    // console.log("the reward will be", toSend);
                    // playerReward -= playerReward*distribution[i]/100;
                }
                pot.participants[startIndex].rewardCollected = true;
            } else if (currentSize == 5) {
                startIndex = 0;
                lastIndex = currentSize;
                // console.log("reward when max 5");
                uint256 playerRewardFor = pot.participants[startIndex].reward;
                for (uint256 i = startIndex; i < lastIndex; i++) {
                    // payable(pot.participants[i].userAddress).transfer(playerRewardFor*distribution[i]/100);
                    payable(pot.participants[i].userAddress).transfer(
                        (playerRewardFor * distribution[i - startIndex]) / 100
                    ); // Changed this line
                    playerRewardFor -=
                        (playerRewardFor * distribution[i]) /
                        100;
                }
                pot.participants[startIndex].rewardCollected = true;
            }
            //till there
            pot.participants.push(
                participant({
                    userAddress: payable(msg.sender),
                    startedAt: block.timestamp, // THE GAME START WILL BE SET AS CURRENT BLOCK.TIMESTAMP
                    endedAt: 0, // OTHER VALUES WILL BE PASSED AS OF DEFAULT FOR NOW
                    durationPlayed: 0,
                    reward: 0,
                    rewardCollected: false
                })
            );
            emit PotJoined(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);
        }
        //fee distribution karo ga;
    }
```

Comment: Important parts of the code are missing, like modifiers, struct definitions. What's on line 101?